# How would you group blockchain smart contracts based on their code structure?

Tags: blockchain

I am trying to classify smart contracts into families or classes. The analogy of what I am trying to achieve can best be described more by Inheritance in modern programming languages. I am trying to classify most of the common forms of smart contracts into classes.